# Find file names with certain extensions

Tags: perl, directory

I want to search a directory for file names with any of the following extensions: `.srt`, `.sub`, `.txt`, `.ass`, `.ssa`.

I would appreciate any input.

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us your code.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way is to use [glob](http://p3rl.org/glob):

```
chdir $directory;
my @files = glob '*.srt *.sub *.txt *.ass *.ssa';
```

Another way is to use [readdir](http://p3rl.org/readdir), but then you have to filter the files yourself, e.g. by using [grep](http://p3rl.org/grep):

```
open my $dir_handle, $directory or die $!;
my @files = grep /\.(?:srt|sub|txt|ass|ssa)\z/, readdir $dir_handle;
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you need to search through an entire directory tree, use [File::Find](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find).